# EC2 instances start shutting down automatically when launched via Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

When I deployed a .NET sample app via Elastic Beanstalk I see below things

1. IT creates an EIP, a Security Group, Launch Configuration.
2. When it starts an EC2 instance, this instance starts getting shutdown automatically. It keeps happening for many times and finally my beanstalk env turns severe or degraded. Nothing happens after that.
3. I am going with default configuration.

What could be the possible reason?

Comment: In a single instance or worker tier environment, Elastic Beanstalk determines the instance's health by monitoring its Amazon EC2 instance status. Elastic Load Balancing health settings, including HTTP health check URLs, cannot be used in these environment types.

Comment: And below are some lines of Ec2 instance logs:
2020/03/20 13:22:29Z: Message: Windows is Ready to use
2020/03/20 13:22:30Z: Windows sysprep configuration complete.